# stored procedure to insert join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Employee` and `Department`. I have joined with primary key and foreign key. Here are two example tables

**Employee**

```
empid(pk)                 
name                      
depid(fk)
```

**Department**

```
depid(pk),
Deptname
```

As I have inserted all the departments names (`Deptname`), but when I insert from employee windows form I select a department name from a combo box and want to insert `depid(fk)` from name.

So please tell me how will be the query in stored procedure for inserting data of employee.
(for update also when employee is updated)

Thanking you

Comment: You should store your `DeptID` in your dropdown list, too - then you already have the relevant ID and you can easily call the stored proc to insert the data with the right `DeptID`

Comment: If you are selecting the department from a combo box, you probably don't need to write a stored procedure. What is your front end? Is it a web page, MS Access, etc? Post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following with your stored procedure input parameters

```
insert into Employee
select @empid, 
       @name, 
       depid 
from Department where Deptname = @deptname
```

Comment: What if two departments have the same name (but different ID's) ??